# Evento de foco no fxml

Tags: javafx, eventos, fxml

No arquivo fxml de uma GUI podemos direcionar o código para um método quando um determinado evento ocorre.
Para eventos de ação, seria algo desse gênero:

```xml
<Button fx:id="btn1" onAction="#actionPause" />
```

Mas quanto ao caso do objeto ter sido focado?
No meu caso, procuro isso para utilizar num `TextField` para remover seu conteúdo padrão e alterar seu estilo.

Peço que, por gentileza, se atenham à resoluções para arquivos fxml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente não da para fazer isso diretamente no fxml. Os eventos que podem ser configurados diretamente no FXML são: setOnAction, Drag & Drop (Arrastar e soltar), Teclado, Mouse, Rotação, Deslizar e Zoom.

Mas no seu código você pode fazer o seguinte:

```java
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{

@FXML
// Link entre o controlador e a interface
private TextField idtextfield;

// ... Algum código

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
    /* Adicionando um listener para capturar mudanças de foco
    *  Obs.: O primeiro componente de cima para baixo normalmente recebe o foco
    *  da aplicação, então tenha cautela 
    */
    idtextfield.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            // newValue terá o valor do foco atual, oldValue o valor anterior
            // Se estiver com o foco o valor será true
            System.out.println(newValue);
         }
    });
```

Veja a lista completa de eventos disponíveis no FXML procurando por setOn: [TextField (JavaFX 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Infelizmente era o que eu temia. Desculpe pelo transtorno, como deve ter notado eu sou novato em relação a isso.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa: o link está quebrado

Comment: Desculpe, na hora de inserir o label ficou no final do link. Corrigido